# Why is there a strong correlation between random number and correct guesses?

Tags: c#, random

In trying to test whether knowing the history of a random number could help predict the future results, I found a strong, unexpected correlation between the average of the number generated, and the number of correct guesses.

The test was supposed to simulate flipping a coin (heads = 0, tails = 1) and if previous attempts were biased towards heads then guess tails and vice versa.

**Why is the sum of the generated numbers always nearly equal to the number of correct guesses in the following LinqPad program?**

```
void Main()
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  var attempts = 10000000;
  var correctGuesses = 0;
  long sum = 0;
  decimal avg = 0.5m;

  for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++)
  {
    var guess = avg < 0.5m ? 1 : 0;
    var result = rnd.Next(0, 2);
    if (guess == result)
    {
      correctGuesses += 1;
    }
    sum += result;
    avg = (decimal)sum/(decimal)attempts;
  }

  attempts.Dump("Attempts");    
  correctGuesses.Dump("Correct Guesses");

  avg = (decimal)sum / (decimal)attempts;
  avg.Dump("Random Number Average");
}
```

Have a made an error in the code? Is this a natural relationship? I expected the averages to converge at 0.5 as I increased the number of attempts because the distribution is fairly even - I tested this with 10bn calls to `Random.Next(0,2)` - but I did not expect the sum of generated numbers to correlate to the number of correct guesses.

Comment: Without reading your code too closely - you realise the `Random` class is a pseudo-randomnumber-generator? As in, its not very random? If you want real(er) random numbers you need something far stronger (and slower) than the `Random` class.

Comment: Think of it this way. You flip a coin 10 times, and all 10 times it landed on Heads. If you flip the coin an 11th time, what are the odds it will land on Heads again?

Comment: @Jamiec: yes, I realize that, and it may affect my original test, but still doesn't explain the correlation :-)

Comment: @user1666620: That was my thinking too, however, I wanted to test it. What I can't understand is the correlation, it's not the test result that I'm unhappy with at this point.

Comment: @JensEhrich have you set breakpoints and stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes, and I saw both correct and incorrect guesses at averages above and below 0.5. So I don't think my guesses are being influenced incorrectly.

Comment: @user1666620 You were on the right track; I should have looked at the per-iteration avg, not the end of run avg. Regarding your first comment, since the numbers are distributed evenly and the average converges on 0.5 (proven by the 10bn calls to Random.Next()) shouldn't the history give me a clue about the future results? In other words, if the average is > 0.5, wouldn't we *have* to have more than a 50% chance of the next number being 0? Otherwise we wouldn't converge on 0.5.

Comment: @JensEhrich tbh I think tossing a coin is a bad example. The result of each individual toss is independent of all previous results. It doesn't matter if you got 100 heads in a row, the odds of getting a heads is still 50% on the next toss.

Comment: @Jens The average of the preceding results may be >0.5, the the expectation for the remainder is exactly 0.5. Therefore the average of the two sets is still >0.5 BUT closer to 0.5 than the first set. That's how it is true that convergence happens even though each remaining result has a 50% chance.

Comment: @BradThomas that makes perfect sense, and now that you've said it, it's painfully obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is this line:

```
avg = (decimal)sum/(decimal)attempts;
```

Makes no sense to divide the sum (based over i to that point) by attempts. Divide by i (EDIT: more precisely i+1) instead for avg to give you something meaningful.

Comment: That's the ticket... can't believe I missed it, but that's what I get for copy and pasting. I'm using `i+1` and it works as expected now.

Comment: Done... had to wait until the time limit was up ;-)

Answer (score -3):

The Random class, without a seed, generates a random number using the current time as seed, meaning that a call of the rnd.Next method in your cycle will result in the same number several times over, depending on how fast your machine goes through the cycle.

Comment: I dont think so.  Since OP is using the same instance, it should be fine.

Comment: That would only affect the results if I created a new Random() for each iteration, which I'm not.